# Javascript DOM error creating nodes

Tags: javascript

First sorry for my English, I am from Spain.
I am new working with Javascript and the problem is that when I try to create a node with Javascript, it does not run.

Checking with firebug I discovered that "`document.body is null`" even though I have specified.

I facilitated the snippet of code that fails:

```
// Crear nodo de tipo Element
var parrafo = document.createElement("p");
// Crear nodo de tipo Text
var contenido = document.createTextNode("Hola Mundo!");
// Añadir el nodo Text como hijo del nodo Element
parrafo.appendChild(contenido);
alert(document.body)
// Añadir el nodo Element como hijo de la pagina
document.body.appendChild(parrafo);
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I am new to the web and I'm learning to use, being English I have some difficulties to understand it, I'll do it slowly but I will have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have that script in the `head` element, it will run before `document.body` exists. Instead, move it to the end of the file, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Here's an example showing that `document.body` is `null` for code running before the opening `<body>` tag has been parsed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>No Body</title>
<script>
alert(document.body === null); // true
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
alert(document.body === null); // false
</script>
</body>
</html>
```